# Xcode 15.3 is unable to resolve package versioning

Tags: ios, xcode

After being upgraded to version 15.3 of Xcode during an upgrade to OSX 14.4, I am no longer able to build my iOS app.  I see the build error;

```
Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of 'strada-ios' match the requirement 1.0.0..<2.0.0 and root depends on 'strada-ios' 1.0.0..<2.0.0.
```

The [strada-ios](https://github.com/hotwired/strada-ios) package is at version `v1.0.0-beta2`. If I examine the packages, in Xcode File/Add Package Dependency page, I see that strada-ios package has the Dependency Rule option 'Up to Next Major Version' greyed out, so I cannot change it.  On the other hand I also have the `chartview` package installed, and the Dependency Rule is not greyed out and I can choose options such as 'Branch' or 'Commit'.

Down the bottom of the window, I am seeing

```
The project already depends on 'strada-ios' with  rule 1.00 Next Major
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I edited the `project.pbxproj` file and removed the following:

```
packageReferences = (
                xyz /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "strada-ios" */,
            );
```

Then I added the package again. I reset the package caches, and I did

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

And then I went to the General setting and added Strada to the Frameworks section.

I am not sure why this worked or what went wrong, so if anyone wants to give a more complete answer, I would be happy to accept it.